# Robotium showing errors from a dependancy library

Tags: android, robotium

I have a project x with dependancy library project. I want to test this project x so I have created a test project and Included the project x as a target project.

In the project x i m calling/working with  couple of API'S of library project and I want to test the same.

while running the test project its showing errors relating to dependancy library project.

Can anyone tell what could be the reason for this?

Help is always appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of errors? Compile time errors? If the thing you are testing cannot compile then it is obvious that you will not be allowed to test it as it has already failed to build.

Comment: any stacktrace, logcat?